# Can I connect aluminium conductor to copper bus bar?

Tags: high-current, busbar

This is a follow-up for the aluminum bar question here: [Aluminum bus bars connection to PCB](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/649672/aluminum-bus-bars-connection-to-pcb)

My design now is based on copper - low resistance, assembly by soldering. For now, this is probably the best. Yet, there are two contacts that I have no choice but to make of aluminum due to the cost involved with copper machining (big chunks cost a lot).

How do I connect aluminum and copper? Do I need to plate either of those with nickel or some other material? Even perhaps gold. Should i solder or press them?

The key requirement - reliability of the joint. The current that will flow there will be between 500A and 1000A.

Comment: Hello again!  Have you investigated any standards / regulations / best practices for this project?  500A+ and lord knows how many volts doesn't sound like something I'd like erupting into an electrical fire because I'd asked some people on the internet about it.

Comment: @TimWilliams thank you for your concern. Yes, i am talking to different people, constantly looking on internet and eventually am going through UL. But at certain points the most effective way of getting ideas is asking on the forum. Voltage is fairly low at this time, before UL all tests will be conducted at 24V.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I connect aluminum and copper?

Dissimilar metals can have issues with [galvanic corrosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galvanic_corrosion), especially in the presence of water/humidity. Plating can help. Another option that I've used in the past is to make both metals the same (but not always possible like you mentioned)

> Electroless nickel plating can provide a robust solution to corrosive
> attack across a range of corrosive mechanisms including galvanic
> corrosion, chemical attack and erosion. Electroless nickel plating
> (EN) can be applied to a wide range of basis metals including steel,
> copper, brass and aluminum alloys. Electroless Nickel plating is
> currently utilized to promote corrosion protection performance across
> a diverse range of industries including heavy equipment, oil & gas,
> power transmission & distribution, automotive, marine and railway to
> name a few.

Source: https://advancedplatingtech.com/blog/corrosion-protection-benefits-electroless-nickel-plating/

Here is a chart on galvanic corrosion compatibility:

[image]
Source: https://torksystems.com/Article/ask-the-experts-electrolysis-galvanic-corrosion/

Comment: Does it have to be Ni to Ni interface, or can it be Ni to Cu?

Comment: Looks like it might be OK.

Comment: Oooh, it could be brass. Thank you!

Comment: I am going to test copper to Ni-plated aluminum. Do you have any suggestions before i do?

Comment: Doesn't look like they are very compatible: https://www.finishing.com/315/03.shtml Aluminum is compatible with itself

Comment: Yeah, I agree. Somehow it looked like a good idea. Am I missing a good way to marry aluminum and copper?

Comment: When talking about bus bars I'd assume considerable measures taken to keep humidity of all sorts out. Without condensating humidity there won't be any galvanic corrosion. See, the subtitle of that chart reads „used in ship repair“. That's a total different category of environment.

Answer (score 1):

There's one major clue to connect aluminum conductors.

Aluminum shows extremly rapid oxidation when exposed to air. The tricky thing is, you can't see the oxide, because it's transparent. So a conductor from Al will always have a fairly thick layer of insulating oxide.
Fairly in terms of connections to make. Some μm are sufficient to have a bad and deteriorating connection.
This is not an issue confined to connections between Al and Cu or other materials. This also causes bad connections between Al and Al!

However this issue has been addressed because aluminum conductors are very common in low voltage high current cabling nowadays because of price and weight.

The basic trick is to remove the oxide thoroughly by some grinding process and to treat the surface with an oxide blocking agent immediately afterwards.

Here's how it can be done with additional tools and materials:
[Connecting Al to Cu](https://www.klauke.com/de/en/correctly-connecting-al-and-cu)

The explanation on this page is rather good in my eyes.

However here's another description of the process to connect Al to lugs etc.
[Making connections to aluminum cables](https://www.incore-cables.com/assembling-aluminium-cables/)

Here you can see the application of oxide blocker. All the materials needed are available at specialised providers.

Another word on galvanic corrosion: If you can't guarantee your busbar is in a dry and non-condensating environment, you should refrain from putting it under power anyway.

Comment: Thank you. Two questions please. Your opinion on plating Al with Ni? And... if the price and mass don't matter, then should we take copper? And then how would we connect two copper bars?

Comment: Plating can solve issues with oxide buildup. However at a bus bar connection there are significant forces on the surfaces. Not all platings can take such forces. Plating process has to be selected carefully. Copper to copper is standard in all high power installations. Mounting is straight forward. It's recommended to clean the surfaces, drill via holes and press them with stainless steel bolts. Calculate a reasonable pressing force and apply it using a torque wrench.